# Подписка в приложении android

Tags: android

Есть приложение для полноценной работы с которым нужна подписка. Возник вопрос 
о работе механизма подписки. К примеру - оформляется подписка на один аккаунт, потом берется несколько (10, 100 и так далее) устройств с этим же аккаунтом - приложение будет работать или на каком то количестве гугл будет блокировать?

Comment: Должно работать. Об ограничениях ничего не слышал.